# Open rar files and read csv files using python

Tags: python, csv, rar

I need to write a program which opens some rar files that contain csv files and read them. I know that there are external libraries for this purpose but what is the best way or library to achieve such a task ?

Comment: Maybe you can use subprocess to decompress a rar file using a system command and then read the csv files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python comes [with batteries included](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included). [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) is one of these batteries.

Support for RAR can be added by an [external library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile).

Answer (score 1):

As stated there is a RAR library for python. That being said you'll still need the unrar program installed on your computer. Using a mac you can install this via homebrew:

```
brew install unrar
```

With this installed, your python script might look something like the following:

```
import rarfile, csv
rar_path = rarfile.RarFile("/path/to/rar_file.rar")
csv_file_name = "rar_file.csv"
rar_file = rarfile.RarFile.open(rar_path, csv_file_name)
csv_reader = csv.reader(rar_file, delimiter=',')

# Should output first line of file (typically CSV header)
print csv_reader.next()
```